# Open link to a local folder

Tags: 2010, browser-compatibility

In our SharePoint 2010 intranet I'm trying to put a link to a local resource into a list of links.

The links are displayed on page, but clicking on them does not open the file or folder.

Putting the link directly into the address bar opens it fine.

This is IE9, the intranet site is using ssl, the site is recognised by IE as local intranet, the links are in correct format (file:///F:/dir1/dir2/readme.txt).

Is there some settings I can switch to enable opening of local links?

Comment: can you paste the link here. doesnt have to be the exact link i just need to see the format

Comment: Um, you mean the link in OP where it says "..., the links are in correct format (file:///F:/dir1/dir2/readme.txt)."?

Answer (score 1):

try these two and tell me what results you get for each

```
<a href="file:///F:/dir1/dir2/readme.txt" onclick="window.open(&#39;file:///F:/dir1/dir2/readme.txt&#39;); return false;" target="_blank">File</a>

<a href="/www.google.co.za" onclick="window.open(&#39;www.google.co.za&#39;); return false;" target="_blank">GooGl</a>
```